# Error deploying shiny app utilizing hydromad

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

So here is the error i am getting from the console. I understand that hydromad package is not on cran but I have added it as secondary repos in packages(Tools options in R studio) and in .R profile file. Still I am getting this error

****Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 2120925...DONE
Deploying bundle: 3058356 for application: 2120925 ...
Waiting for task: 720810692
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 3408182
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  error: Building package: hydromad

########################## Begin Task Log ################################

```
[2020-04-24T06:51:09.225825780+0000] Execute script: packages/build/sys.sh
+ set -e
+ apt-get update -qq
+ apt-get install -y libapparmor-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapparmor-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
Need to get 67.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 229 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor-dev amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11 [67.8 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 67.8 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libapparmor-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 119718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor-dev_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor-dev:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libapparmor-dev:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) ...
```

########################### End Task Log #################################

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 720810693 failed: Error building image: Error fetching hydromad (0.9-26) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: hydromad (0.9-26)
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Package 'hydromad 0.9-26' was installed from sources; Packrat will assume this package is available from a CRAN-like repository during future restores
Execution halted****
```

Can anyone help me resolve this error? Will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is quite specific, so I would recommend to use a more specialized resource. The good news is that package hydromad has its [own forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hydromad-users)